# Converting First Generation Managed Package to Second Generation (2GP) Packages

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, second-generation-packaging, 2gp, 2gp-ama

In light of the new Winter '20 release and that 2GP will be Generally Available, it means we'll be able to develop and release managed packages on the AppExchange through the new 2GP processes.

In the [release documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_2GP_GA.htm?edition=&impact=), it mentions that First Generation packages cannot be converted to 2GP:

> Use 2GP to create new managed packages. You can’t currently convert a first-generation package to a second-generation package.

Question:

1. How do we manually convert our 1GP managed package to a 2GP? I'm interpreting the above quote to mean that "there's not out of the box way to convert one package type to the other" but that there should be a way to do it manually.
2. An already AppExchange released package - is there no hope in keeping that namespace for the 2GP version that we'd like to create?  Or is there no way to create a 2GP "version"?

Comment: There was a webinar on this topic last week - doesn't look like the recording is available yet, but that covered a lot of these questions. I'd wait for that to go up and then ask more questions in the Managed Packages group in the Partner Community:
https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/ISV_Tech_Enablement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**November 2020 Answer**

Converting from 1GP to 2GP is in Developer Preview in the Winter '21 (Oct 2020) release. You can join the Partner Community group which has all of the instructions for getting your Packaging Org enabled to pilot the functionality:

https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F94V000000PkSm

**Previous Answer (November 2019)**

There were roadmap sessions at Dreamforce '19 which covered the timeline for this (Safe Harbor and all):

In the Summer '20 release, the ability [to convert a 1GP managed package to 2GP will be in Pilot](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_preview_package_migration.htm)

In the Winter '21 release, the feature will be GA

The slides haven't been posted yet, but if they are, they'll be here:

https://success.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q3A000021ea1UUAQ#/session/a2q3A000002BJMTQA4

Comment: So all in all: If you have a 1GP, continue iterating on it as a 1GP for at least another year. If you are not already using DX and scratch orgs to build the package, now is a good time to start, but you'll still have to MDAPI the source into your golden packaging org. Keep your ears open for more info on the migration path.